# Envolver parte de uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Estou testando uma função para selecionar a parte de um título que vem após o sinal de dois pontos:

```
$('.carousel .item .carousel-caption h2').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        console.log(val);
        var string = val.substr(val.indexOf(":") + 1);
        console.log(string);

        var foo = val.replace('/('+string+')/g', '<span>$1</span>');
        console.log(foo);
    });
```

Eu consigo selecionar a parte que preciso, mas não consigo incluir as tags. No console, a variável foo aparece igual a variável val.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode concatenar uma string numa expressão regular literal como está tentando (na verdade, você acabou usando uma string em vez da regex literal). Use o construtor `RegExp`:

```
var foo = val.replace(new RegExp('('+ string + ')', 'g'), "<span>$1</span>");
```

Depois, não esqueça de substituir o valor do elemento (suponho que a intenção seja essa):

```
$(this).html(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

```
   $('.carousel .item .carousel-caption h2').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        var string = val.substr(val.indexOf(":") + 1);
        var re = new RegExp(string, "g");
        var novo = val.replace(re, '<span>'+string+'</span>');
        $(this).html(novo);
    });
```

Comment: Marcelo, bom ter conseguido resolver e colocar aqui o código final. Porem seria correto marcar como aceite a resposta que o levou a solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ou da forma descomplicada:

```
$('.carousel .item .carousel-caption h2').each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(':', ':<span>') + '</span>' );
    });
```

Ou com verificação da existência do **`':'`**:

```
$('.carousel .item .carousel-caption h2').each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(':', ':<span>') + ($(this).html().indexOf(':') > 0 ? '</span>' : '') );
    });
```